# ActiveRecord: Cannot use keyword token as method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Ruby 1.9.3-p327, Rails 3.2.13

I have the following model:

```
class ActivationToken < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :create_token

  attr_reader :token

  private

    def create_token
      self.token = 'abc123'
    end
end
```

When I create a new ActivationToken record, and call `my_token.token` I get `nil`, but if I reference is as a hash, `my_token[:token]` I get a value.

Why is that?

Comment: Try accessing it as `my_token.token` after removing `attr_reader :token`

Comment: If I set it up as attr_accessor, it works. I don't want the value to be writable though, hence declaring it as attr_reader.  Feels like some kind of name collision, but I cannot find where it would be the case.  I'm using SQLite locally.

Comment: added answer below; maybe that will help

Answer (score 0):

Remove `attr_reader :token`
Rails (before 4.0) uses `attr_accessible` to permit the attributes which are writable and accessible via hash.
Rails 4.0 uses [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) for same purpose.

On removing both `attr_reader` and `attr_accessible` for `:token`, your attribute won't be able to get written explicitly, but can be read; which is what you want.

Comment: I'm wondering if ActivationToken and token would somehow compete with each other.  I like having attr_reader as it documents the intent of the code.  I'm ok sticking with the hash notation for now, but I'd just like to understand why it's doing this.  Will update once I try a few more things